# Meaning and use of どの when not in a question

Tags: translation, particles

Can someone please help me to understand these sentences from the Tobira textbook?

秋田市の「竿燈祭り」、仙台市の「七夕祭り」、そして青森市の「ねぶた祭り」。**どの**祭りもすごいスケール！毎年、日本だけじゃなくて、海外からも観光客がたくさん来るし、とても人気のある祭りだよ。

I am confused about this sentence どの祭りもすごいスケール！.  I've never really understood how どの is used outside of a question, so I'm not sure what it means here.  I think it might mean something like, each of (the three) festivals is very large?

How specifically are どの and も functioning in this sentence?

Comment: どの and も give the sense of "whichever".  So, "whichever festival, it's on a grand scale."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「どの」＝「いずれの」 = "***each and every*** (one of the items mentioned)"

> 「どの + Noun + も + Verb or Adjective Phrase」 =
>
> "Every (noun) [that have been mentioned] is/does ~~~."

This 「も」 does **not** mean "also".  It expresses the ***complete kind of affirmation or negation***.  In other words, it is saying that there is no exception (to what one is saying).

> 「どの[祭]{まつ}りもすごいスケール！」 = "Each festival is of an awesome scale!"

Comment: 'Each and every' is a highly emphatic phrase in English. Does どのXも carry the same weight in Japanese?

Answer (score 0):

> どの+noun+も+positive predicate = every noun ...
>   どの+noun+も+negative predicate = no noun ...

So in this case:

> Every/each festival is of a grand scale.