# fragmented statement and いつの世も

Tags: reading-comprehension, cleft-sentences

> Speaker talking about a painting with a goddess and an owl
>
> 「ミネルヴァの梟は夜に飛ぶ──と記したのはヘーゲルでしたか。知恵の女神の聖鳥である梟もまた知恵の象徴」
>
> **「そんな梟が夜に飛び立ったのを人が知るのは、夜が明けて朝になってから。いつの世も人は起こったことしか知ることができないのです」**
>
> 「未来のことがわかれば……なんて、誰しも思ってしまいますけどね。ふふ」

The people who know that the owl flies off at night, after morning dawns. いつの世も people only know that this occurs.

I find it difficult to follow the middle statement in terms of how to interpret ...が知るのは、夜が明けて朝になってから。with a period. and what いつの世も is describing.

Along with what any of this has to to with knowing the future.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> そんな梟が夜に飛び立ったのを人が知る**のは**、夜が明けて朝になってから(**です**)。
>   It is (only) after dawn breaks and morning comes that people (can) realize the owl has flied off at night.

This is a [cleft sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/19208/5010) where the ～から part is pulled out for emphasis. です at the end of the sentence has been omitted. The original sentence is:

> 夜が明けて朝になってから、人はそんな梟が夜に飛び立ったのを知ります。
>   People realize the owl has flied off at night (only) after dawn breaks and morning comes.

---

いつの世も means "in any age", "regardless of the era", etc. It's in the same vein as [どの～も](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30850/5010) grammar.

> いつの世も人は起こったことしか知ることができないのです。
>   Regardless of the era, people can only know things that have (already) happened.